# Можно ли вписать в объект динамическое свойство?(то которое мы не знаем как называется заранее)

Tags: javascript, объекты

есть объект

```
const names = [массив строк];

const obj = {
   names[0]: names[0],
   names[1]: names[1]

}
```

мне нужно чтобы св-во обьекта называлось как в массиве и чтобы имело значение как в массиве

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать например с помощью скобочной нотации:

```js
let arrayOfData = ['test1', 'test2', 'hello'];
let obj = {};

obj[arrayOfData[0]] = arrayOfData[0];
obj[arrayOfData[1]] = arrayOfData[1];
obj[arrayOfData[2]] = arrayOfData[2];

console.log(obj.hello);
```

или заключить ключ объекта в квадратные скобки (*ES6*) вот так:

```js
let arrayOfData = ['test1', 'test2', 'hello'];
let obj = {
  [arrayOfData[0]]: arrayOfData[0],
  [arrayOfData[1]]: arrayOfData[1],
  [arrayOfData[2]]: arrayOfData[2],
};

console.log(obj.hello);
```

Answer (score 0):

Со свойствами объекта в JavaScript можно работать как с элементами словаря:

```
const names = [массив строк];

const obj = { };
obj[names[0]] = names[0];
obj[names[1]] = names[1];
```